# Is it possible to use an "in" clause with pyignite sql

Tags: ignite

I am not sure if this is supported or not. I am trying to work out if you can use a parameterized query to submit a list of values (similar to how you would use ANY (%s) in psycopg, for eg). Obviously this works in plain SQL - but I cant figure out how to make it work in pyignite client session. A simple example would be:

```
create table testme(key int primary key, value varchar);
insert into testme values
 (1,'1')
,(2,'2')
,(3,'3');
```

What I am aiming to do is something like this (in pyignite)
`select * from testme where key in (1,2)`

The obvious

```
from pyignite import Client

# connect
cnc = Client.connect()

key_lst=[1,2]

with cnc.sql('select * from testme where key in (?)', query_args=[key_list]) as res:
    for row in res:
        print(res)
```

returns no data - so the syntax is obviously wrong. Yes I could use binary objects to get the rows, but that isn't the question - and this is obviously a contrived example. Real use case is not so simple to put it mildly.
Published documentation doesn't cover this (unless I am going blind - which is always possible), so I am not sure if its an omission or just not supported....